# PyQt Toolbar Triggered

Tags: python, pyqt, signals-slots, qtoolbar

I can't understand this

`tb.actionTriggered[QAction].connect(self.toolbtnpressed)`

on here actionTriggered[QAction] <- what is this ? it's a list ?

Comment: Where is that from? I've never seen it used like that. It should be tb.actionTriggered.connect(self.toolbtnpressed)

Comment: @buck54321 you can edit the question and add `python` to the tags.

Comment: @eyllanesc Cool. I'll watch for that a little closer.

Comment: It's custom `__getitem__` accesss, which selects a specific overload (i.e. signature) of the `actionTriggered` signal. Without it, the default overload is selected.

Comment: PS: the [actionTriggered signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#signals) actually only has one overload, so explicitly selecting it is redundant.